# The "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml" task was not found

Tags: c#, xml, slowcheetah

I am getting error when I complied my solution as following:

```
Error 1 The "SlowCheetah.Xdt.TransformXml" task was not found. Check the following:
```

1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class.

2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface.

3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory. BulkNoticeGenerator

Can you any help me on this issue.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The solution or project in question is using SlowCheetah MsBuild tasks for XDT transformation.

You will need to do one of the following:

- Install [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) Visual Studio extension
- Install [SlowCheetah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlowCheetah/) NuGet package into the project that is using it.

Comment: I am using in win forms "app.config", already installed/uninstalled slow cheetah, rebooted the system but consisting the same problem. Can be there any software/hardware min requirement if I am using VS 2010 with Windows 7, also updated Nuget packages.

Comment: @AnjanKant Did you try creating a completely new project and adding a transform to it? Does it manifest the same problem or is the problem limited to your existing project?

Comment: Damir, I have tried as you provided me in previous message but same issue coming out.